# What is the difference between a desktop app and a non-desktop app in windows

Tags: windows

I found something on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation page that doesn't make sense to me.

Under requirements, there is:

```
Minimum supported client:  Windows XP **[desktop apps only]**
Minimum supported server:  Windows Server 2003 **[desktop apps only]**
```

Now I understand the difference between an app with a GUI and one that runs as a service, but in the end, they are both processes.  I've never heard of this kind of restriction on a function call like this.  Is this just poor documentation, or is there something more to this?

Comment: That means "not available in a Phone or Store app".  There's a company whose name resembles a fruit that made desktop apps a bit yesterday.

Comment: @HansPassant - Did you mean Rapsberry Pi? :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the introduction of Windows 8, Metro, and Windows Store, API documentations now specify which framework(s) they are supported on.  Not all desktop APIs are available to metro/mobile apps, and vice versa.

Comment: So Desktop apps means services and non-desktop processes and this is just a poor choice of wording?

Comment: "Desktop apps" refers to classic Console, GUI and Services that existed prior to Win8/Metro/Mobile.  Metro/Mobile introduced a new API framework that does not apply to classic apps, and restricts some of those classic APIs for apps being migrated to Metro/Mobile.